# Aplicativo Android fecha ao realizar cálculo

Tags: java, android, android-activity

Estou fazendo uma app que possui uma calculadora bem específica da área médica. No AVD, o cálculo aparece divinamente bem. Em dispositivos reais, dá erro e a aplicação é fechada.

Alguém pode me ajudar ai?

**CalcActivity:**

```
package unicatolicaquixada.edu.br.dia_diagnsticodeincidentalomaadrenal;

private EditText txtDVP, txtDT, txtDSC;
private Button btnCalcular, btnLimpar;

private double dvp, dt, dsc;
private String wr, wa;
private TextView firstPercent, secondPercent;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_calc);

    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Sair");

    txtDVP = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtDVP);
    txtDT = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtDT);
    txtDSC = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtDSC);
    btnCalcular = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnCalcular);
    btnCalcular.setOnClickListener(this);
    btnLimpar = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLimpar);
    btnLimpar.setOnClickListener(this);
    firstPercent = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView54);
    secondPercent = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView55);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()){
        case android.R.id.home:
            startActivity(new Intent(this, MainActivity.class));
            finishAffinity();
            break;
        default:break;
    }
    return true;
}

@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    if (view.equals(btnCalcular)){
        if (txtDVP.getText().toString().equals("") || txtDT.getText().toString().equals("") || txtDSC.getText().toString().equals("")){
              wa = "0,00%";
              wr = "0,00%";
        }else {
              dvp = Double.parseDouble(txtDVP.getText().toString());
              dt = Double.parseDouble(txtDT.getText().toString());
              dsc = Double.parseDouble(txtDSC.getText().toString());
              wa = String.valueOf(washoutAbsoluto(dvp,dt,dsc));
              secondPercent.setText(wa+"%");
              wr = String.valueOf(washoutRelativo(dvp,dt));
              firstPercent.setText(wr+"%");
        }

    }else if (view.equals(btnLimpar)){

        firstPercent.setText("0,00%");
        secondPercent.setText("0,00%");
        txtDVP.setText("");
        txtDT.setText("");
        txtDSC.setText("");

    }
}

private double washoutAbsoluto (double densidadeVenosaPortal, double densidadeTardia, double densidadeSemContraste){
        double wa = 100*((densidadeVenosaPortal-densidadeTardia)/(densidadeVenosaPortal-densidadeSemContraste));
        return arredondaValores(wa);
}

private double washoutRelativo (double densidadeVenosaPortal, double densidadeTardia){
        double wr = 100*((densidadeVenosaPortal-densidadeTardia)/(densidadeVenosaPortal));
        return arredondaValores(wr);
}

private double arredondaValores (double valorArredondar){
    DecimalFormat formatador = new DecimalFormat("0.00");
    valorArredondar = Double.parseDouble(formatador.format(valorArredondar));
    return valorArredondar;
}
```

Comment: Você conseguiu capturar alguma exceção? Aonde exatamente no seu código o erro acontece?

Comment: Comece por abrir a janela `Logcat` e ver o erro que lhe deu, e coloque o erro na pergunta para ajudar lhe ajudar a obter respostas.

Comment: @LeandroAngelo, o erro acontece quando eu coloco pra calcular. Insiro os valores. O erro só acontece em um dispositivo físico.

Comment: Abra a janela LogCat. La você tem muitas informações, inclusive, o ponto onde ocorreu a exceção e o motivo.